# Browser focus on PWA apps after sending SMS via SMS url

Tags: sms, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA that exchanges public keys between friends using SMS.

The process begins with one person clicking a link to a partially populated
 SMS url and opening a window - the portion of the url which is populated is
 the body, which points to a dynamic url generated by the app.

For example:

```
"sms://&body=http%3a%2f%2facme.com%2findex.php?id=128409234823432"
```

What remains is the selecting of a contact from your phone book to send the link to.

The problem I am facing is the browser loses focus to the SMS app and there is no
 way to programmatically bring the browser back to the foreground if the SMS is sent
 or even canceled - This causes confusion for non-tech users as they think
 the app has been closed.

Is there a way to return to the browser after the user sends the SMS?